# How to disable automatic inclusion of header files in CodeBlocks

Tags: c, mingw, codeblocks

Back in the day I used to do C programming in Turbo C where If you write this C progam:

```
int main(){

   printf("Testing...!");
   return 0;
}
```

It won't work until you add `#include <stdio.h>` at the beginning. But if I run the same program in CodeBlocks it works.

Is it the Compiler or the CodeBlocks which automatically includes the header file ? and how would I stop this ? Do I need to configure Turbo C compiler ( which is borland I guess ) to CodeBlocks Instead of MinGW ( that I am currently using ) ?

Comment: I don't think that Code::Blocks or the compilers add any header files by their own. Most probably your warning level is so low that the warning about a missing declaration don't pop up, or Code::Blocks does not show it. And because the linker happily links against the standard library, `printf()` is found and linked. Raise the warning level to the maximum! -- Just tried: a simple `gcc test.c -o test` already reports the missing declartion.

Comment: But it should report that as error not a warning.

Comment: Programming without prototypes is K&R style, and still done(!)... ;-) Some compilers allow it, depending on the standard requested. You can make most compilers emit warnings as errors, though.

Comment: Note that GCC version 4.x and earlier defaulted to the C90 standard, which more or less allows the code in the question — using `puts()` would be safe, but strictly, a function taking a variable argument list, like `printf()`, must have a prototype in scope even in C90 (otherwise, the behaviour is undefined — which means it might work anyway, but it isn't guaranteed).  GCC version 5.1 and later default to C11 (the compiler never defaulted to C99), which means that prototypes (well, function declarations, preferably prototyped) are required.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the "Editor setting" in CodeBlocks. There is an option for "Default Code". You can modify it according to your need.

Comment: That does nothing

Answer (score -1):

As @thebusybee suggested raising the warning level, fixed the problem and here is how to do it:

1. Goto **Settings** -> **Compiler**
2. Under **Global compiler settings** goto **Compiler settings** -> **Compiler Flags**
3. Then under **Warnings** section mark the flag saying **Treat as errors the warnings demanded by strict ISO C and ISO C++**

Answer (score -1):

There is a plugin in CodeBlock that does this, you just have to disable it and this auto-generated source code would no longer be included.

Go to **Plugins** and go to **Manage plugins...**. Locate the **Header Guard** plugin and select it, then click the **Disable** button.